# Connection Error - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having trouble connecting from my application server which is a Windows 2008 R2 box to MySQL Server box also running on Windows 2008 R2.

The Laravel application reports the error:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out'
```

The odd thing is I **can** connect via MySQL Workbench from the application server to the MySQL Server using exactly the same credentials and port, and the connection is quick.

Can anyone shed any light on how this can be?

Comment: Are you accessing it remotely by chance?

Answer (score 2):

Check .env file or config\database.php file, set correct username, password, database name, ip and port.

Answer (score 0):

It was a firewall setting applied by our host provider. Thanks anyway.

Comment: can you explain more? running into the same problem