# Connect to staging database from a local environment - Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, database-connection

## Goal

Locally on my **Mac OS**, I'm trying to connect to my **staging database** that are running and hosted on my Ubuntu VM.

---

## Steps

In my `config/database.php`

```
'connections' => [

    'mysql'       => [
    'driver'      => 'mysql',
    'host'        => env('DB_HOST'),
    'database'    => env('DB_DATABASE'),
    'username'    => env('DB_USERNAME'),
    'password'    => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'unix_socket' => env('UNIX_SOCKET'), <---- Need it here 
    'charset'     => 'utf8',
    'collation'   => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'      => '',
    'strict'      => false,
    ]

],
```

In my .env I have

```
DB_HOST=45.55.88.88
DB_DATABASE=staging
DB_USERNAME=john
DB_PASSWORD=***
UNIX_SOCKET=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock  <---- I'm not sure what to put here
```

I am not sure what to PUT as my UNIX_SOCKET since database.php need it.

I kept getting

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I believe that because my path to the UNIX_SOCKET is wrong.

How could I configure something like this?

## Update

Base on @dparoli's answer. I update my database configuration not using **UNIX_SOCKET** any more.

```
'connections' => [

    'mysql'       => [

        'driver'      => 'mysql',
        'host'        => env('DB_HOST'),
        'database'    => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'username'    => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'    => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'port'        => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'charset'     => 'utf8',
        'collation'   => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'      => '',
        'strict'      => false,
    ]

],
```

now I got

> PDOException in Connector.php line 49:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out

---

I've tried looking more into the settings of my `staging` VM

## sshd_config

Will `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` play any roles in this at all ? 
Is it because I disabled password log-in and only allow log-in via public key ?

I've tried both

**PasswordAuthentication no**

and

**PasswordAuthentication yes**

---

## netstat

I ran `netstat -ln`, I got

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17123         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11300           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
...
```

I saw **0 0.0.0.0:3306** there.

---

## php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 60

and 

memory_limit = 1000M
```

---

## /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address = *
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/

____
```

## Result

> PDOException in Connector.php line 49:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out

How can I stop that ?

What else can I check or try ?

Comment: I don't think you can connect to remote host using unix socket. What you might do is to establish an SSH tunnel and connect to localhost on tunnel port.

Comment: Have you checked your MySQL permissions, that the user credentials you have entered are allowed from the host you are trying to access from?

Comment: @ChrisTownsend : Good thinking !!! I tried that and I got `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '45.55.88.88' (60)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to connect to another host via a Unix socket, that is not possible because sockets, usually, are only directly visible to the system on which they are created.

For your staging env to work you have to comment out the `unix_socket` config line and add a port:

```
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
```

And configure mysql to listen on that port.

Comment: I update my database configuration base on your answer. I got **SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out** I also added the details in the post.

Comment: You have to configure mysql for remote access, and open 3306 port in your vm box firewall: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905581/connection-error-sqlstatehy000-2002-operation-timed-out and here http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: I ran `netstat -ln` I got this to display `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN `

Comment: What should this line look like to allow remote access from other database clients or Laravel app ?

Comment: @ihue Look for `bind-address` option in your MySQL config (typically in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`). With that option you can specify allowed remote IPs

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be primarily a networking issue between the Host and Guest.

- First, let's get the Host to talk to the Guest (VM)

  - Login to VM (assuming you are using VirtualBox, other VMs will be similar)
  - Run ifconfig and note down the IP address. It will be something like 10.0.2.5
  - Go to VM instance window -> Menu -> Network adapters:

    - set Adapter to NAT
    - Click on "port forwarding" at the bottom
    - Create new record (click the + icon on right hand side)
    - Set Host IP = 127.0.0.1
    - For guest IP address enter the value you got earlier (10.0.2.5 - your IP may be different)
    - In both cases for port use 3306
  - Click on OK button twice and you should be out of the settings screens and all done
- Verify you can connect to MySQL instance via command line on the VM

  - Open a terminal window on VM
  - Run this command `mysql -hlocalhost -ujohn -p`
  - Enter the password when prompted and you should be able to connect. If not, try the following

    - `mysql -h127.0.0.1 -ujohn -p`
    - If you still can't connect then make sure you have the correct password
  - Once you are able to connect locally, it's time to connect from Host (Mac)
- Use the following command:

  - `mysql -h127.0.0.1 -ujohn -p`
  - Enter the password when prompted
- If you still can't connect, try turning off the firewall on Guest/Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

What you could try if you have `SSH` access to the VM (or any remote actually) then you can try port forwarding the connection over `SSH`:

```
ssh foo@bar -L 3307:localhost:3306
```

Now port `3307` on your local machine is acting as port `3306` on the remote machine. In your config file you can then go

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3307
```

The downside of this approach is that you need to have a terminal session setup and running when you want to use your local environment.

Comment: That's a cool trick, but I am not sure, if I want to keep doing my SSH when I want to connect to mysql all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Operation timed out is most likely caused by the firewall. You can fix this by running these commands on your VM:

```
sudo ufw allow out 3306/tcp
sudo ufw allow in 3306/tcp
```

If this doesn't work, check if there is any traffic coming on port 3306 by using this command:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth1 port 3306
```

replace `eth1` by your network interface, which you can find using this command:

```
sudo ip link show
```